# Can't get the Datasets library to install in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to install the datasets package (from Huggingface). Everything seems to be working, but when I try to actually import it

`from datasets import load_dataset`

I get an error in

```
import pyarrow

import pyarrow.lib as _lib
```

Specifically:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

I've tried reinstalling it multiple times, through Pip, Pip3, Conda. I tried reinstalling pyarrow. Nothing seems to make it work. That said, the error message was different before.

Interestingly, when I try upgrading Pip, I keep getting
`WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yarrow`

Any idea what I can do to make it work?

Many thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.